# Question on Do Carmo

Tags: differential-geometry

In Do Carmo's book Differential Geometry of Curves and Surfaces section 1.2 I'm trying to proof the following:

Let $ \alpha: I \rightarrow \mathbb{R}^3 $ be a parametrized curve and let $ v \in \mathbb{R}^3 $ be a fixed vector. Assume that $ \alpha '(t) $ is orthogonal to $ v $ for all $ t \in I $ and that $ \alpha (0) $ is also orthogonal to $ v $. Prove that $ \alpha (t) $ is orthogonal to $ v $ for all $ t \in I $.

Any hint or some help please?

Answer (score 2):

Ok a hint, differentiate $\alpha(t)\cdot v$.

Answer (score 2):

We have $(\alpha (t) . v)^{ '}= \alpha^{'} (t) . v + \alpha (t) .v ^{'} = 0$ for all $t$ ( note that $v^{'} = 0$ , because it is a fixed vector).

So, the function $\alpha (t) .v , t \in I $ is constant with $\alpha (0) . v = 0$. Then $\alpha (t) . v = 0$ for all $t.$